# How to access Request parameters in Spring MVC Interceptors

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC Interceptors, i.e implementing "HandlerInterceptor".

Inside my preHandle method how to get Request parameters passed from browser? we need to pre process based on request inputs from browser

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    request.getParameter("myData") // this is returning null        
}
```

The data is passed from front end using jquery post request

```
var rq = 'myData:{"custDetails":{"CustId":"123456"}}';
$.ajax({
        url : "myhost/TestController/testMethod",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        },
        data : rq,
        success : function(data) {
                if (data.status == false)
                        //location.href = "failure.html";
                else
                        $('#result').html(data.test.msg);
        },
        error : function(data) {

        }
```

I am able to get Request Header details as is not parameter details am i doing any mistake Please advice?

Comment: You aren't posting parameters but a json string as body of your request. What is it that you need to do what you cannot do in a controller?

Comment: @ M.Deinum we need to check authorization to particular module(for us each controller is a module)and we need to place this code logic in a common interceptor which can intercept all URLS. Yes i need to access request body , but after accessing it should be available to Controller also :-(

Comment: Why do you need everything in the request body? Isn't it possible to send certain things as parameters or headers? That would make it easier, else you would have to wrap the request and for that you would need to build a `Filter` instead of an interceptor. Next to that do you really need to build your own solution or could you use something like Spring Security instead that way you could use expressions for security.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes we need to reuse existing security (so we are not planning to use spring security) do you have any example of using filter, we are able to wrap request in filter but not success in injecting some beans using spring auto-wire into filter class. can you share any solution? thanks in advance

Comment: The fact that you have a security solution doesn't mean you cannot use Spring Security... But alas you have chosen to build your own. Spring has a logging filter take a look at that, it also wraps the request so that the request can be streamed to the logfile but still be processed.

Comment: Can you please try data: JSON.stringify(rq) in your ajax method?